# QUERY DSL target classes are cleaned every time I do a code change

Tags: querydsl, spring-tool-suite, m2e

generated Qclasses in the target directory is always get cleaned when I do a small code change and save.Therefore I have to do maven updates to generate QClasses every time. Is there a better approach without having to update maven every time?

Comment: I added the m2e tag to this question since the Maven Integration for Eclipse seems to be involved here.

Comment: It Happens to the classes which are in the common library            <plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
       <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <phase>generate-sources</phase>
               <goals><goal>add-source</goal></goals>
               <configuration>
                   <sources>
                       <source>common-libs/src</source>
                   </sources>
               </configuration>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by rolling back to version 1.1.2 of maven apt plugin from version 1.1.3

Answer (score 0):

3 years after you answered yourself (thank you btw) I'm experiencing this exact same issue too with STS and the apt-maven-plugin. Unfortunately 1.1.3 is still the current release (at the time I posted this). There is a related GitHub issue page [here](https://github.com/querydsl/apt-maven-plugin/issues/31) but it has gone quiet as well.

While I appreciate that rolling back to 1.1.2 makes the problem go away, I'd still like to see a plugin fix or at least an explanation for the cause of this problem.