# QueryDSL generated classes keep getting deleted in maven project in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, querydsl

I am using QueryDSL in a maven Spring Boot project in Eclipse, with Spring DevTools activated, and everything works fine, except for the fact that the QClass used in QueryDSL get deleted, and next time I try to relaunch the project (or it tries to auto-reload through Spring DevTools) I get an error, and I must go through "Run as"->"Maven generate-sources" again.
I am not sure what exactly triggers the deletion, but I noticed that for instance adding or removing a file will trigger the deletion. Removing DevTools didn't help.

Is there a way to prevent those constant deletion, or to make sure that the classes are automatically regenerated afterward?

Here are the relevant part of my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>REDACTED</groupId>
    <artifactId>REDACTED</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>REDACTED</name>
    <description>REDACTED</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    [...]
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    [...]
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/customfolder</outputDirectory>
                            <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/customfolder/</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: If I try to (re)launch the application after the QClasses where deleted, and without regenerating them, I get a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on those QClasses, which makes sense.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem after upgrading from Java 8 to Java 11.

Comment: @RenéReitmann I am also using Java 11, so it might be related to this. I did comment all the part using QueryDSL to continue working on the project, and when I uncomented them later to check if things were still working fine, I found out I didn't suffer from this problem anymore, though...

Comment: I also have the same problem when using Java 11

Comment: Related [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42265583/query-dsl-target-classes-are-cleaned-every-time-i-do-a-code-change/)

Answer (score -1):

> Change the pom.xml as follows. It will work

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
     <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>

  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
      <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

> and add the plugin

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.3</version>
          <executions>
             <execution>
                 <goals>
                   <goal>process</goal>
                 </goals>
         <configuration>
             <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
             <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
          </configuration>
         </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: I tried replacing querydsl-core by querydsl-apt as you advised, changing back target/generated-sources/customfolder to target/generated-sources/java, and removing <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>, but I still have the same problem as before...